# When using has_many with custom foreign_key i get an undefined method error, in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-many

The first model:

```
class FaqGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :faqs, :foreign_key => 'group_id', :order => 'position'

  acts_as_list
end
```

The second model:

```
class Faq < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :faq_group, :foreign_key => 'group_id'

  acts_as_list :scope => :faq_group
end
```

The controller:

```
def new_faq
  @group = FaqGroup.find(params[:id])

  @faq = @group.faqs.create(question: 'lorem', answer: 'ipsum')
```

end

When i load that in the browser I get the following error:

```
undefined method `faq_group_id' for #<Faq:0xb56fcde4>
```

So, basically when I try to create a new associated object, the foreign_key just gets ignored. If i give up the custom :foreign_key everything works great.

Another observation would be that if I do:

```
@group = FaqGroup.find(params[:id])
@faqs = @group.faqs
```

it WORKS ok, so it seems that it has problems using the foreign_key only when it creates new associated objects.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Check the [belongs_to association with the foreign key option](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to).

As mentioned there,

For `foreign key` in `belongs_to`-

"Specify the foreign key used for the association. By default this is guessed to be the name of the association with an “_id” suffix. So a class that defines a belongs_to :person association will use “person_id” as the default :foreign_key. Similarly, belongs_to :favorite_person, :class_name => "Person" will use a foreign key of “favorite_person_id”."

So in context with it, the error is because  you defined:

```
class Faq < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :faq_group, :foreign_key => 'group_id'
```

This association requires `faq_group_id` as the foreign key and not the `group_id`.

So is the error -

```
undefined method `faq_group_id' for #<Faq:0xb56fcde4>
```

Comment: From my understanding the :foreign_key parameter is used if you want to specify a DIFFERENT foreign key than the default one. And this is what i am doing. If I wanted to stick to the default one (faq_group_id), there wouldn't have been any need to change the :foreign_key parameter at all.

Comment: This is not the proper association because you are saying that `faq belongs to faq_group` but you are associating the foreign key to be group's id. How can a foreign key be of `group_id` when group is never related to faq? There should be a relation between two tables i.e. `group` and `faq`. As told you earlier, the foreign key should be suffixed at the end by `_id` where it `belongs to`.